# MVC C# Select Where

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to add filter by ID for the following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = from o in new MainDBContext().OffLinePayments
                select new EditOffLinePayment 
                {
                    ID = o.ID,
                    Amount = o.Amount 
                };
    return View(model);
}
```

What I would like to do is the following:

```
public ActionResult Index(long? id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        var model = from o in new MainDBContext().OffLinePayments
                    **Where Assigned_ID == id**
                    select new EditOffLinePayment 
                    {
                        ID = o.ID,
                        Amount = o.Amount 
                    };
        return View(model);
    }
    else 
    {       
        var model = from o in new MainDBContext().OffLinePayments
                    select new EditOffLinePayment 
                    {
                        ID = o.ID,
                        Amount = o.Amount 
                    };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var model = from o in new MainDBContext().OffLinePayments
                   where o.Assigned_ID == id
                    select new EditOffLinePayment 
                    {
                         ID = o.ID,
                        Amount = o.Amount 
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that the compiler doesn't let you write `where o.Assigned_ID == id` in the query.

That's because `id` is a `Nullable<long>`, which is not implicitly convertible to a `long` (which `OffLinePayment.Assigned_ID` presumably is).

You need to write `where o.Assigned_ID == id.Value` instead. Take a look at what the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) property does so that you don't get any surprises.

Comment: It appears the problem was that he was trying to write `Assigned_ID == id` instead of `o.Assigned_ID == id`.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner, shorter and much more readable syntax would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(long? id){ 
    using (var ctx = new MainDBContext())
    {
        var entities = ctx.OfflinePayments.Where(e => !e.HasValue || e.Assigned_ID == id.Value);

        var model = entities.Select(e => new EditOfflinePayment { ID = e.ID, Amount = e.Amount }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```